# ASP.NET Component with custom property form

Tags: .net, asp.net, components, designer, custom-properties

I'm developing a custom DataGridView control for internal use and I'd like to add a custom property option where it launches a WinForm for adding custom properties. Think of the Columns property designer of the DataGridView where you click a button with the text "..." on it and it opens a WinForm where you can add different BoundColumns. This is what I exactly like to do but I don't know how or even where to start. How can one accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to know (the base): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx

This is an helpfull example (inside the first link): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az5kdaz0.aspx

If you want build a custom DataGrid, you need to build a control that inerith from DataGrid control, after read linked documents on top, you can be able to add Properties with required attributes for use it in Control.

(sorry for bad english, i'm italian!).